# Don't understand Tweepy error

Tags: python, api, tweepy

I'm just getting the hang of python, and I'm wanting to start using it with API's and such. I installed Tweepy, got my Twitter keys, and followed the setup process on their website. It was going fine till, well, here

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('qwertyuiop', 'asdfghjkl')
auth.set_access_token('qazsecftgbhujmkolp', 'plokmjuhbgtfcdeszaq')

api = tweepy.API(auth)

user = tweepy.api.get_user('twitter')

print user.screen_name
```

(with my real keys, of course)

This returns with the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tweeter.py", line 8, in <module>
    user = tweepy.api.get_user('twitter')
  File "/home/jeremiah/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 243, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/home/jeremiah/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 189, in execute
    raise TweepError('Failed to send request: %s' % e)
tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: local variable 'auth' referenced before assignment
```

Which I just don't get. Defining `auth` is the first thing I do. Also, this is taken right off of the site's introduction course.

It seems it's all fine until the `user = tweepy.api.get_user('twitter')`. If I take that + everything below it out, it's fine, or if I replace it with

```
public_tweets = api.home_timeline()
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print tweet.text
```

it's fine.

So what is it? Is Tweepy screwy, is my computer screwy, or am I just missing something obvious?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you sure it's fine if you take out `print user.screen_name`? Looks like the error is on the `user = ...` line

Comment: However the error it's talking about an `auth` object in `binder.py`, not yours. Probably an issue, [see here](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/binder.py#L173).

Comment: @Claudiu Yep, I messed up. Edited.

Comment: `user = api.get_user('twitter')`?

Comment: @cdonts What exactly does that mean? In the actual Tweepy code there is a problem the creator needs to fix, or does that just mean I can't use auth as a variable?

Comment: You can use `auth` as a variable, but the error code is just not talking about that object (but an object also called `auth` in `binder.py`). Actually it seems like there's an error in the documentation's example-

Comment: @DavidZemens Well, I did that, and it doesn't give an error anymore. However, it returns information from the actual official "Twitter" Twitter account, so it looks like it look at whatever account is in the parenthesis. Also, it just seems a little strange that the official instructions from the Tweepy site don't work. Hmm. Anyway, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `get_user` method of the [`tweepy.API` class](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.4.0/api.html) (which you've assigned to your variable name `api`).

Try:

```
user = api.get_user(id='__your__username__')  # returns the user specified by id
```

Or:

```
user = api.me()  # returns YOUR authenticated user object
```

The reason you will need to specify your username in the parentheses, or use the `me()` method (instead of the literal `'twitter'` (which returns the user object from [@twitter](https://twitter.com/twitter) because you've asked it to get *that* user!) is because the [`get_user` method](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.4.0/api.html#user-methods):

> Returns information about the specified user.
>
> **Parameters:**
> id – Specifies the ID or screen name of the user.
>
> user_id – Specifies the ID of the user. Helpful for disambiguating when a valid user ID is also a valid screen name.
>
> screen_name – Specifies the screen name of the user. Helpful for disambiguating when a valid screen name is also a user ID.

Regarding your code, note the difference between this, which raises an exception:

```
user = tweepy.api.get_user('twitter').
```

And this, which does not raise an exception

```
public_tweets = api.home_timeline()   '## NOT tweepy.api.home_timeline()
```

In the latter (which does not error) you are correctly using your `api` variable to call the `home_timeline` method.

Comment: Well that does work. But right beneath that it describes the `api.me` method. That should return my info, so I don't have to go through all those hoops, but it still doesn't work when I try `user = api.me` then I `print user`.

Comment: Are you doing `user = api.me` or `user = api.me()`?

Comment: Wow. Always that simple. Guess I'm too tired to be doing proper thinking. Thanks for answering my dumb questions anyhow.

Comment: Hahah cheers sometimes you just need another set of eyes looking at the problem.